# C#でHTMLを操作したい

Tags: c#, windows, html

C#上でjQueryのように簡単に任意のtagを操作したいです。
ASP.NETではなく、Windowsアプリケーションです。

要は、HTMLファイルを突っ込んだら、色々HTMLファイルをいじって返してくれるようなプログラムを作りたいと思っているのですが、HTMLをどうやったら簡単にいじれるかで悩んでます。
C#で使えるjQuery likeなライブラリは無いでしょうか？
もしくは、上記のようにHTMLをいじりたい場合のオススメの方法などありましたら教えていただきたいです。

Comment: こちらの投稿をきっかけに、メタに[「いいライブラリはありませんか」系のQ&Aを考える投稿](http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/q/1512/30)を投げました。ご意見あればぜひお寄せください。

Comment: ありがとうございます。読ませていただきました。
なるほどと納得する内容で、今後当該質問のような質問をする時は気を付けたいと思います。

Comment: フィードバックありがとうございます!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)が鉄板だとは思いますが、DOM操作にXPathを使う必要があります。
LINQを使うことも出来ますが、CSS Selectorに比べると煩雑です。
あと過去にWebサイトを静的生成するプロダクトで使った時は、思ったほど処理速度が出なかった覚えがあります。

HtmlAgilityPackにCSS Selector機能を追加した[Fizzler](https://code.google.com/p/fizzler/)というライブラリもあります。
こちらの方がよりjQuery寄りだと思います。

あと若干オーバースペックかもしれませんが、もっとブラウザ寄りの操作を行いたいのであれば[PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/)の[C#バインディング](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PhantomJS/)を使う方法もあります。

Comment: 軽く見てみましたが、Fizzler良さそうですね。CSSのSelectorそのまま使えるのは重宝しそうですね。
ちょっとPhantomJSは理解しきれてません。Fizzlerまで試してみて挑戦してみます。

Answer (score 1):

jQueryの様な操作感という事なので移植したものやC#上から呼び出す方法などを検討しました。
その結果、
GitHubで[CsQuery](https://github.com/jamietre/CsQuery)を発見しました。
また、[呼び出す](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22216177/how-to-call-jquery-function-from-c-sharp)方法もありそうです。

場合によっては[JavaScript上でC#を呼び出す](http://qiita.com/akmiyoshi/items/16c4a65731f8ec32e233)ことも検討可能です。

Comment: CsQueryはFizzlerに比べて[かなりパフォーマンスが良い](http://blog.outsharked.com/2012/06/csquery-performance-vs-fizzler.html)みたいですね。

Comment: 情報ありがとうございます。
CsQuery良さそうですね。順番に試しているので、感想などは書けませんが、試してみようと思います。

Answer (score 0):

まあ、既出ですがやはり、HtmlAgilityPackですね。
使用事例ですが、Webサイトのクローラで抽出に使っています。
いささか時間が経過しているので記憶があやふやにはなっていますが、それほど大きく頭を抱えるトラブルはなかったかと思います。

Comment: 情報ありがとうございます。  
HtmlAgilityPackお試し中です。